# ERROR Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONTINUE'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, cursor

I need some Help making this MySQL Cursor, I have been following this guide:http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/. I am trying to make a cursor to iterate through a table and create a list of names one row at a time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_people_table ( @people varchar(4000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @v_finished INT;
    DECLARE @v_name nvarchar(255);


    --Main Cursor
    DECLARE people_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Person Name]
    FROM [dbo].[People];

     -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET @v_finished = 1;


    OPEN people_cursor;

    get_name: LOOP

    FETCH people_cursor INTO @v_name ;

    IF @v_finished = 1 THEN
    LEAVE get_name;
    END IF;

    SET @people = CONCAT(@v_name,';',@people);
    END LOOP get_name;

    CLOSE people_cursor;

END
```

mySQL ERROR Message

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure build_people_table, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONTINUE'.
Msg 136, Level 15, State 1, Procedure build_people_table, Line 41
Cannot use a CONTINUE statement outside the scope of a WHILE statement.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure build_people_table, Line 47
Incorrect syntax near 'LOOP'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure build_people_table, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure build_people_table, Line 61
Incorrect syntax near 'LOOP'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure build_people_table, Line 74
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
```

Comment: you need help converting this mysql sp over to sql server you are saying?

Comment: I am trying to make a cursor and saving the list into a variable. I am not converting. I just want to Create a MySQL cursor. but i don't understand the error

Comment: I don't understand the tsql tag, the sql server source code, and the sql server error messages

Comment: I may be lacking sleep, but I don't think you know what server you are attached to at the moment. Or maybe you are using a microsoft GUI that is reporting error messages differently. idk

Comment: I am using Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio. I also removed the t-sql if that tag is incorrect sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows it end to end in Mysql (the technology you are saying you are using).

Note, it is best to use

```
select group_concat(`Person Name`) from People;
```

For this. But for whatever reason, you seem to want to write a stored proc for it, maybe for learning purposes. It is important to note that cursors are like **tremendously slow.**

Also note that your output buffer (the *out* parameter) has a great chance of overflowing. There is a lot of data that can get in there. So I changed it from a varchar(4000) to TEXT.

### Schema

```
create table People
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    `Person Name` varchar(200)
); 

insert People(`Person Name`) values ('John Henry'),('Kim Billings'),('Gertrude Smith');
```

### Stored Proc

```
drop procedure if exists build_people_table;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE build_people_table ( OUT people_out TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE v_name nvarchar(255);
    -- DECLARE bFirst boolean DEFAULT TRUE;


    -- Main Cursor
    DECLARE people_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `Person Name`
    FROM `People`;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;


    OPEN people_cursor;
    set @people='';

    get_name: LOOP

        FETCH people_cursor INTO v_name;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE get_name;
        END IF;
        SET @people:= CONCAT(v_name,";",@people);
        -- SET @people:= CONCAT(@people,";",v_name);
    END LOOP get_name;

    CLOSE people_cursor;
    set people_out:=@people;
    -- select @people; -- used for debugging
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test

```
set @saveHere:='';
call build_people_table(@saveHere);
select @saveHere; -- show results

'Gertrude Smith;Kim Billings;John Henry;'
```

Comment: I think the important error message is 'Cannot use a CONTINUE statement outside the scope of a WHILE statement.' the declare NOT FOUND handler. And fixing the LOOP in the sql

Comment: That is the way it is done see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: I will continue to look. Is it a runtime issue or is it a create the proc issue

Comment: I think it would be better to just convert it to T-SQL cursor

Comment: you have this marked as mysql. I get back to asking, what is your server

Comment: no you don't, look at the tags, and look at the comments

Comment: Sorry about that I put the wrong tag is there without realizing it. And I am putting it is the wrong Database aswell

Comment: I had the wrong connection open. I have a  SQL Server 2014 DB on one server, and MySQL on a different server. I was on the wrong connection. Was trying to migrate some scripts, so i recreate the cursor, and i though of just stick with the SQL Server instead. And that is why I though of converting it to T-SQL.  There was nothing wrong.